# Python: How to implement plain text to HTML converter?

Tags: python, html

I'm trying to implement a simple "plain text to html" converter, but can't figure out why it doesn't work as intended.
So here's what I want to do - let's say we have a text:
`text = 'Hey! /n/nIt was really nice to meet you! /n/nOur team hopes to see you soon! /n/n/nBest regards, /nYour new team.'`
So for such text, what I want to do is:

1. Wrap all the text inside the `<p></p>` tags
2. Each line should be wrapped into `<p></p>` tags
3. If there's only a single `/n` that means that this is a new line and we just have to wrap it into `p` tags
4. but if there are multiple `/n` then each `/n` starting from 2nd should be replaced as `<br>` tag, and then for the last `/n` just wrap a line into `p` (see point 2)

here's the code i've made for now:

```py
def convert_text_to_html(text):
    # Split the text into lines using /n as the delimiter
    lines = text.split('/n')

    # Initialize an empty new_lines_replaced string
    new_lines_replaced = ''

    for line in lines:
        # Initialize a count to keep track of consecutive /n
        count = 0

        # Check for consecutive /n characters at the beginning of the line
        while line.startswith('/n'):
            count += 1
            line = line[2:]

        # Add the corresponding number of <br> tags
        br_tags = '<br class="ProseMirror-trailingBreak">' * count

        # Wrap the line in <p> tags
        new_lines_replaced += f'{br_tags}<p>{line}</p>'

    # Wrap the entire string with <p> and </p> tags
    return f'<p>{new_lines_replaced}</p>'
```

but instead it returns only `p` tags and no `br` tags, here's the output:
`<p><p>Hey! </p><p></p><p>It was really nice to meet you! </p><p></p><p>Our team hopes to see you soon! </p><p></p><p></p><p>Best regards, </p><p>Mojob team.</p></p>`

UPD: alright guys, thanks to all of you, but i decided to move forward with empty `<p></p>` tags instead of `<br>` ones, so found a solution to work this way:

```py
def convert_text_to_html(text):
    # replace each `\n` with empty <p> tag - it closes the previous one and opens a new one
    new_lines_replaced = text.replace('\n', '</p><p>')

    # add initial <p> tag for the first line
    new_lines_replaced = f'<p>{new_lines_replaced}'

    return f'<p>{new_lines_replaced}</p>'
```

Comment: `\n` is 1 character and you remove 2 from line

Comment: if you step through with a debugger what do you see

Comment: why don't you close the `br` tag? `<br/>`

Comment: oh, i guess i messed up with `split` and that doesn't work as intended... but thanks, if my line would start from `/n` then i really should use `line[1:]` and not 2

Comment: do you have `\n` or `/n` in your string

Comment: right, it should be `\n` but the task remains the same, right?

Comment: `p` tags inside `p` tag is semantic wrong, you can't have a paragraph in a paragraph

Comment: by doing `text.split('/n')` how many `/n`'s do you think are still in the stings in the list

Comment: yeah, that didn't work as well, i had couple of empty strings in the list then, i though about using `re.split` but don't know how to handle multiple consecutive `\n` in it:
```python
    lines = re.split(r'(\n\n|\n)(?=[^\n])', text)
print(lines)
```

Comment: '
['Hey! ', '\n\n', 'It was really nice to meet you! ', '\n\n', 'Our team hopes to see you soon! \n', '\n\n', 'Best regards, ', '\n', 'Your new team.']
<p><p>Hey! </p><br class="ProseMirror-trailingBreak"/><br class="ProseMirror-trailingBreak"/><p></p><p>It was really nice to meet you! </p><br class="ProseMirror-trailingBreak"/><br class="ProseMirror-trailingBreak"/><p></p><p>Our team hopes to see you soon!
</p><br class="ProseMirror-trailingBreak"/><br class="ProseMirror-trailingBreak"/><p></p><p>Best regards, </p><br class="ProseMirror-trailingBreak"/><p></p><p>Your new team.</p></p>
`

Comment: @rioV8 Since `<br>` is a [void-element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Void_element) you don't have to close it

Comment: so like it does its job, but sometimes there's a `\n` at the end of the line, and `\n\n` are like a distinct line which causes empty `<p></p>

Comment: @DerSchinken HTML5 should be valid XML but because a lot of people did not close all the tags that should be closed they changed the rules and invented the `void` tags

Comment: you can **Edit** your question instead of adding large blocks of text in a comment

Comment: @rioV8 Yes that's maybe true but the rule exists, so whether you write `<br />` or `<br>`, it's nothing more then a coding style preference

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to check if the line starts with a `/n`, this will never be true since `str.split(x)` splits the `str` at all occurrences of `x` and removes `x` from the str. Also you don't need to check for `/n`s in the for loop since every `line` is indeed a new line.

And you're getting empty `<p></p>` because you don't check if the line is empty or not

Here is the improved code:

```py
def convert_text_to_html(text):
    # Split the text into lines using /n as the delimiter
    lines = text.split('/n')
    
    # Initialize an empty new_lines_replaced string
    new_lines_replaced = ''
    
    for line in lines:
        if not line == lines[0]:  # Check if this is the first iteration, since we don't want an unwanted br at the start of the html
            # Add <br> tag
            new_lines_replaced += '<br class="ProseMirror-trailingBreak" />'
        
        # Now the line can be empty since /n/n exits and that would lead to [..., "", ...] when split
        # So we need to check if the line is not empty
        if line.strip():  # .strip because there can be spaces between /n's and that would make line true since it's not empty
            new_lines_replaced += f"<p>{line}</p>"
    
    # Wrap the entire string with <div> and </div> tags (Since wrapping <p> inside a <p> is semantically wrong)
    return f'<div>{new_lines_replaced}</div>'
```